# How to pretty print url in address bar using web.config rewrite module?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, iis, web-config

I am currently using PHP for the different pages on my site. Each page has an 'include' at the top and the bottom to include the header and footer. Currently what I have tried below 'pretty prints' the url in the address bar but then the header and footer includes aren't recognized so the css and js files aren't loaded. I would like to keep my href's as they are but when or as the page loads, rather than have somesite.com/article.php?id=15, I'd like it to show somesite.com/article/15. I am on a windows server so .htaccess files are irrelevant. I have read that you can do the reverse of what I've tried, but I am not familiar with the xml properties of web.config. Most documentation that I have read was in regards to .htaccess. Even if I definitively search for parameters in regards to web.config or IIS. I have IIS Manager 10 on my PC but it doesn't have the url rewrite module available in it and the url rewrite module that is available to download from the MS website fails to install.
Here is what I have tried:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rule 1h">
                <match url="mprofile/([^/]*)\.php$" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="m_profile.php?id={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>

        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The problem with that is that if I enter in the address bar somesite.com/mprofile/15, it loads the page but fails to load the css, js files as well as the opening/closing html tags that are in the 'include' header and footer pages. I can enter the url in its raw form and it works perfectly but I would like to maintain the 'pretty print' format.

**EDIT**

I've also tried this, and when I upload it to my server and try to access the page it gives an error that the url contains a count in a { } expression that is not valid.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="m_app_profile.php?id={R:1}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="^m_app_profile/([^/]+)/?$" />

            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: If this is a new project look at using a micro framework that handles all the routing for you

Comment: @charlietfl It's an existing project. :/

Comment: @charlietfl Please see edit.

Comment: Sorry but I know just enough to be dangerous regarding IIS . Am adding IIS tag for better coverage